# How to convert a website to iOS app

Tags: ios, web-applications, web, ipa

I have developed a website, and now I would like to transform this website to an iOS application.

There is a tool in Android which is called "Website 2 APK Builder" which does what I want. I don't know if there is something similar in iOS.

If not, how could I do this, without using any framework if possible?

Answer (score 3):

Apple doesn't allow apps of this type. If your app is just wrapping a web site, they will reject it. Here is a quote from their [list of app rejection reasons](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/rejections/):

> Your app should be engaging and useful, and make the most of the
>   features unique to iOS. Websites served in an iOS app, web content
>   that is not formatted for iOS, and limited web interactions do not
>   make a quality app.

So, forget about wrapping your web site into an iOS app. Your options are to create a native iOS app from scratch, or you can [optimise your web site](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/optimizing-mobile-web-apps-ios) to give iOS users the best possible experience when using your site through Safari.

Comment: And using an UIWebView showing the website, but changing the screens of the website to a more "iOS" style would be rejected as well?

Comment: If your app contains only a UIWebView, then I would guess they'll reject it. If your web site works perfectly well in Safari, then that's where Apple will say it belongs. Safari will let you create a home screen icon for a web site.

Answer (score 0):

I should point out that frameworks exist for building **hybrid apps**, which are cross-platform apps built in HTML/CSS/JavaScript but packaged inside native apps and distributed as native apps. The [Cordova framework](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview/) or its derivatives such as PhoneGap and Ionic allow you to build apps this way. Apple still won't allow you to just wrap a random web site though, you have to create something which ["feels like" a native app](http://www.awesome-robot.com/article/PhoneGap_and_the_Apple_Store/).